# Matrix Multiplication code in Python

Tags: python, function, class, matrix

i have a job for school in Python.
i need to create a class called "Matrix" and give it some actions i can do on it.

untill multipication all went great! but here i have a problem.
i was pretty positive that my code was on target! but now, i just dont know what to do.

```
class Matrix:

    def __init__(self,lst):
        self.mat = lst
        self.dim = (len(lst), len(lst[0]))

    def get(self,i,j):
        if (i) <= self.dim[0] and (j) <= self.dim[1]:
            return self.mat[i-1][j-1]
        else:
            print "index not in matrix!"
            return None

    def mult(self,other):
        new_mat = []
        for r in range(1,self.dim[0]+1):
            new_row = []
            res = 0
            for c in range(1,other.dim[0]+1):
                res += (self.get(r,c) * other.get(c,r))
                new_row.append(res)
            new_mat.append(new_row)
            new_row = []
        return Matrix(new_mat)
```

it always tell me that im put of index, but i dont undestand how

the input im checking is

```
A = Matrix([[1,0,2],[3,1,1],[4,5,2],[0,2,8]]) 
B = Matrix([[1,3],[4,2],[0,5]])
C = A.mult(B)
```

can anyone take a look at this one and tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Why do beginners not read error messages?

Comment: well i read the error. and it looks like im trying the wrong index. but i dont get why.

Comment: As a sidenote there is fun lying around [operator overloading](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for this kind of stuff. Try it out, being able to do `C = A * B` or `C[2,3]` is pretty neat. And it would just take 2 little changes in your class.

Comment: and if you have a question abut beginners and error message you can ask it in a new thread :-) ill try and answer

Comment: @spectras that looks cool. but im not allowed to do that :-(

Comment: Note: get used to zero based indexes, adding 1 so you can substract 1 in the next step just complicates things.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Note taken

Answer (score 0):

Hey i changed your code a bit. Din't use the get method. Have a look

```
class Matrix:

def __init__(self,lst):
    self.mat = lst
    self.dim = (len(lst), len(lst[0]))
    self.rows=[lst[i][:] for i in range(self.dim[0])]
    self.columns=[[lst[i][j] for i in range(self.dim[0])] for j in range(self.dim[1])]

def get(self,i,j):
    if (i) <= self.dim[0] and (j) <= self.dim[1]:
        return self.mat[i-1][j-1]
    else:
        print "index not in matrix!"
        return None

def __multList(self,list1,list2):
    if len(list1)==len(list2):
        return sum([list1[i]*list2[i] for i in range(len(list1))])

def mult(self,other):
    matrix=[]
    for i in range(len(self.rows)):
        rows=[]
        for j in range(len(other.columns)):
            rows.append(self.__multList(other.columns[j],self.rows[i]))
        matrix.append(rows)
    return Matrix(matrix)
```

and with your matrices,

```
A = Matrix([[1,0,2],[3,1,1],[4,5,2],[0,2,8]]) 
B = Matrix([[1,3],[4,2],[0,5]])
C=A.mult(B)
print C.mat
```

you get

```
[[1, 13], [7, 16], [24, 32], [8, 44]]
```

Comment: thats really nice. but its not the answer to my question. im looking for my mistake, i want to understand in order to get better